# PostgreSQL, trying to copy column of dates from csv file to table's column

Tags: postgresql, csv, date, sqldatatypes

I have a PostgreSQL table that contains an empty column of type 'date'

I'm trying to copy date values from a CSV file.

But It raises this:

```
COPY books (publication_date) FROM 'path/to/file/pub.csv' CSV;
```

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "11/31/2000"
```

This value is at index 8178 of the CSV, so it's not the entire file that's faulty.

I don't understand why, as the date seems perfectly fine.

So, how can I fix this or make Postgres ignore the faulty dates?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "11/31/2000"
```

> I don't understand why, as the date seems perfectly fine.

Well, november has only 30 days, so the date is indeed invalid.

Comment: That's right, wrote a function that changes these faulty lines and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the datestyle to the required format.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/7.2/sql-set.html

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE

SET datestyle = DMY;